# Google App Engin: page of localhost:8080 gives error?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-inventor

I use appinventor2 and im trying to set tinywebdb2. Though i've fallowed the steps in http://beta.appinventor.mit.edu/learn/reference/other/tinywebdb.html carefully. it fails to open localhost as its shown in picture[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUoNe.png)

my app.yaml

application: tinywebdb-1092
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: .*
  script: main.py

Comment: probably this setup guide can help?
https://sites.google.com/a/wellesley.edu/wellesley-cs117-fall14/goodies/tinywebdb-services/creating-a-custom-tinywebdb-service

Answer (score 0):

Go to app.yaml and change `runtime: python` to `runtime: python27`
See if that works for you